# Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done

Tags: c#

Hello I'm still getting this error and I try different solutions but it's not work !
Here are my code

I put the connection string in app.config file like this :

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ComputerManagement" 
connectionString= "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=.. ; Integrated Security=false"/>
```

and in the button_click in the form I put the following code  :

```
  try
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(GetConnectionString());
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Clients(C_name,C_phone ,C_mob ,C_add , C_email ,C_account) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4 + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "')";
            command.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception) { throw; }
```

Comment: What is the error? What line is it on?  What have you tried?

Comment: I think error text is in the question's title, but you are right - that's confusing

Comment: BEcasue you're string concatenation there are several reasons why this could fail, and it leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  Change the string concatenation to use `OleDBParameter`s and see if it works or if you get a more meaningful error message.

Comment: @DavidGoshadze The error in the title Sir. Thank you

Comment: @DStanley ; I tried it  , still I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

You missed `.Text` on  `textBox4` in your statement

and also you should construct command from connection object like:

```
OleDbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
```

in your code command doesn't know anything about connection.

Comment: Yes , That's true . I fix it , but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: @DavidGoshadze I add the the command = conn.CreateCommand(); but I still get the same error

Comment: `command.CommandText = .......;

                command = conn.CreateCommand();
                              
                command.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();`

Comment: should be in order conn.Open; command = conn.CreateCommand(); command.CommandText = ....... command.ExecuteNonQuery(); conn.Close();

Comment: I order it ; but unfortuantley I'm still getting the same error. Thank you

Comment: Hmmm... Do you know which line throws an exception?

Comment: It's in line 19 which mean in the `conn.open() ;`

Comment: Phew... that's provider or connection string problem. Pity I didn't ask earlier :)

Comment: Phew!
For that reason I put the connection string first in my question

Comment: I didn't blame you. I did blame myself :)

Comment: No worries. I'm just got nervous from this error. I try to check everything in the code. but It still don't work.

Comment: The code has nothing to do with this error at the moment. I think connection string is most probable cause. Can you connect to provider with ServerExplorer?

Comment: Look; I try this code in another form and it's working well
`try
            {
                OleDbConnection connect;
                OleDbCommand command;

                connect = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Micro);
                command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;                         
                ..........           
            }` 
But when I put the connection string in the app.config and call it in the form ; this error appear.

Comment: In another words when I write the connection string inside the click_button event it's working well. I think the problem happening when I call the connection string from the app.config. there is something wrong and I can't detect it